# Removing Dashed Borders of CartoDB Polygons

Tags: carto, mapnik

I've created a CartoDB map with a bunch of different multipolygons and it is displayed with a CartoCSS color ramp I created.  However I've noticed that I cannot rid my map of the dashed lines that separate the polygons. I initially thought this was due to my polygons being mulitpart instead of singlepart, but even working with a singlepart polygon, I still get those dashed lines.

My CartoCSS has no mention of line-color, line-width, or line-opacity to it.  I've also tried to specifically set the line-opacity and line-width to 0 in hopes that this would take care of it. Here is my CartoCSS:

```
#test{ 
  [fcst<=68]{polygon-fill:#DFF22C;} 
  [fcst<=66]{polygon-fill:#BFE526;} 
  [fcst<=64]{polygon-fill:#9FD81F;} 
  [fcst<=62]{polygon-fill:#7FCC19;} 
  [fcst<=60]{polygon-fill:#5FBF13;} 
  [fcst<=58]{polygon-fill:#3FB20C;} 
  [fcst<=56]{polygon-fill:#1FA506;} 
  [fcst<=54]{polygon-fill:#009900;}  
       ....etc.....
  [fcst<=6]{polygon-fill:#660066;}
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm seeing

[image]

Here's a URL to my visualization: http://cdb.io/1Ig5cGq

---

It looks like what I'm seeing is actually slivers of the basemap behind the polygons. @andytilia's comment helped me find this. This is interesting because the polygons match up completely.  Even when zooming in all the way the "gap" only appears to be a very faint dotted line.

Here's what I see on a dark map background:

[image]

Zoomed in all the way:

[image]

I'm wondering now if this is an bug in CartoDB or it's rendering engine Mapnik.  Or perhaps there is something I need to do to my geometry (ST_Scale?) that I could use to "grow" my geometry by like a half meter and remove those lines?

Comment: Is there another layer involved? When I open your visualization first I see the shapes without the boundary for less than 1 second then the boundary (and maybe some transparency?) is added.

Comment: There wasn't any other layers except for the map.  Your idea of an additional layer though, led me to the idea that what I'm actually seeing is the map itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No geometry editing needed!

I was able to get around this by applying the same styling of the polygons to the polygon outlines as well.

```
#test{ 
  line-width:1; line-opacity:0.4;
  [fcst<=68]{polygon-fill:#DFF22C; line-color:#DFF22C;} 
  [fcst<=66]{polygon-fill:#BFE526; line-color:#BFE526;} 
  [fcst<=64]{polygon-fill:#9FD81F; line-color:#9FD81F;} 
  [fcst<=62]{polygon-fill:#7FCC19; line-color:#7FCC19;} 
  ...etc...
```